# PHP form passing post data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm sorry if the question has been answered before but I have I have populated with data from PHP ie. dropdowns with options. I am using CodeIgniter and wish for the php variables to be sent back to my controller.

I have found the following Ajax post function using JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

In my case I have a controller called main and a method called postBack() so I'm assuming I would enter the following:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: http://localhost/project/main/postback,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

however I have no idea how to pass the PHP variables using the code or what to enter in the  data or datatype fields, once again I apologise if this has been answered but I can't seem to figure this out.

Many thanks in advance

can someone tell me if I'm overcomplicating this if I perform the above can I simply grab all of the data back on the controller using:
$_POST

Comment: Where do you set the value of the `data` array?

Comment: what you mean by "httpI" in ajax url?

Comment: you can add the data in a JSON format in the form of KEY VALUE pairs in data attribute. Then use JSON_DECODE in the PHP controller to get the associative array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery for this

In php page use

```
<a href='#' onclick="showDiv('<?php echo $val; ?>')" class="classname">Edit</a>
```

Jquery function

```
<script>
function showDiv(id)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {                       
        //do something as it is equivalent to an ajax success function
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","your-php-page.php?id="+id,true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

enclose your url with single quotes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sel").change(function(){
var data=(this).val();
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'http://localhost/project/main/postback',
      data: data,
      success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    }

    });

})

})
</script>



  //html part  
    <select id="sel">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You misspelled, it's `http://`. And I'm not sur of the url `main/postback` maybe. Don't know how url are defined in CodeIgniter. Anyway your answer wouldn't work in production environment.

Comment: its ok theres a function called base_url() that will automatically change the base URL I just didn't include in the example

Comment: better use site_url(). it provides the url from controller part, hence u dont need to include index.php everywhere

Answer (score 0):

PHP variables can be passed either as a variable like this

```
localhost/project/main/postback/variable
```

In this variable should be treated as the parameter we are passing.
So here You could use

```
'localhost/project/main/postback/'.<?=$variable?>.''
```

else you could assign the variable value to any hidden field in the form and can be access it from posted form data itself as `$this->input->post('hiddenfieldname');`